# Handling missing data from table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am retrieving data from the database and then using transformations to transform it to how I need it.  At the moment it looks something like this

```
return [
    'data' => [
        "col1" => $tableData->col1,
        "col2" => $tableData->col2,
        "col3" => $tableData->col3
    ]
]
```

The problem is, not all database tables will have a col2 for instance.  As such, I am looking to do something like this

```
return [
    'data' => [
        "col1" => $tableData->col1 or '',
        "col2" => $tableData->col2 or '',
        "col3" => $tableData->col3 or ''
    ]
]
```

The above does not seem to work though, if a column does not exist I get something along the lines off

> Undefined property: stdClass::$col2

Is there any way I can handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check with `hasProperty`, more info here http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.hasproperty.php

So, you could have something like this:

```
return [
    'data' => [
        'col1' => $tableData->hasProperty('col1')?$tableData->col1:'',
        'col2' => $tableData->hasProperty('col2')?$tableData->col2:'',
        'col3' => $tableData->hasProperty('col3')?$tableData->col3:'',
    ]
]
```

Comment: What that not require me to make it a Reflection Object?